# Resolving .NET assembly reference to a different name?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, clr-hosting

My project references **Library1.dll** and **Library2.dll**.  **Library2.dll** has a dependency on **Library1.dll**, but it was compiled to reference it by a different name, **Library1.Net40.dll**.

Is there an nice way tell my application to redirect all references for **Library1.Net40.dll** to resolve to **Library1.dll**?  Maybe something similar to the way you can redirect versions using a <bindingRedirect>?

I've got a solution that handles the *AppDomain.AssemblyResolve* event, but it's a bit of a hack and am hoping there's a better way to do this.

***Edit:
For anyone's reference, here's how I ended up solving it using the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event](http://chrisfulstow.com/redirecting-assemblies-in-net) to redirect to a different assembly.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried playing with the [<codeBase> element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb.aspx)?

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Library1.Net40"
                              publicKeyToken="..."
                              culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"
                      href="Library1.dll"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

(Untested; no idea if it works.)

**CF: Am putting this update here, because it's a bit long for the comments :)**

Good idea, thanks. I got the redirect working but it complains because the names are different, here's the log:

```
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Project/bin/Library1.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Project\bin\Library1.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Library1, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: NAME
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

When a **PARTIAL** resolve is applied, the **ASSEMBLY NAME must match the filename**. However the LOCATION of the file can be different.

Otherwise the Fusion Binding Log will report "WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: NAME" and be unable to bind.

(Good news: it is possible to *rename* the assembly DLL to match the Assembly Name.)

For example:

```xml
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
    <codeBase version="12.0.0.0" href="bin/Newtonsoft.Json.12/Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

This resolves `bin/Newtonsoft.Json.dll` and `bin/Newtonsoft.Json.12/Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, depending on version (6-10 or 11-12, respectively). The NAME successfully matches the *filename* even though the directory path is different.

N.B. "bin" is itself *part* of the href to the alternate version; adjust as relevant depending on the application base, which is different than the probe path. In the case about, which is running under IIS, the app base is a level above the bin directoy. (See "LOG: Appbase = .." in the Fusion Log.)

Unfortunately the MSBuild process does not honor the directory structure of Referenced Assemblies automatically, regardless of any configuration files. Set the project to *not* "Copy Local" the alternative assembly versions and then copy them as part of a secondary process ensuring the correct structure is maintained. If any compiled assembly take the alternate version as a directly reference it might be good to ensure that none are "Copy Local" by default.